# $\langle f_n,g \rangle $ converges to $0$ for all $g$, does this imply $\|f_n\|$ converge to $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

I need to prove or disprove
$f_n\in R(\displaystyle \mathbb{T})$  sequence of integrable functions in $[0,2\pi]$. $$\forall g\in R(\displaystyle \mathbb{T}), \langle f_n,g \rangle \xrightarrow[]{n\rightarrow\infty} 0 \Rightarrow  \|f_n\|_{L_2}\rightarrow0$$

What I've been thinking is this:

$\hat{f_n}(m)= \langle f_n,e_m \rangle, \hat{f_n}(m) \to_{n\to\infty }0$.

$S_Mf_n=\sum_\limits{m=-M}^{M}\hat f_n(m)(t)e^{imt} \xrightarrow[]{M\to\infty} f_n(t)$ in $L_2$.

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\lim\limits_{m \to \infty}\sum_{-M}^{M}\hat{f_n}(m)(t)e^{imt})=\lim\limits_{m \to \infty}(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{-M}^{M}\hat{f_n}(m)(t)e^{imt})=0$ if $S_Mf_n$ converges uniformly ($M\to\infty$), but not always. If we can change the order of the limits , we get

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\lim\limits_{m \to \infty}\|S_Mf_n-f_n\|_{L_2})= \lim\limits_{m \to \infty}(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\|S_Mf_n-f_n\|_{L_2})= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\|f_n\|_{L_2}=0$

So a counter example could be a sequence of functions such that $S_Mf_n$ doesn`t converge uniformly, and $\hat{f_n}(m) \to 0$ for all m.

Can anyone provide a counter-example or point out my mistake?

Comment: With 'integrable', do you mean Riemann-integrable?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. As Lorenzo Quarisa pointed out, your assumptions may have some problems (you should probably assume that $f \in L^2(\mathbb T)$, from which it would follow that also $f \in L^1(\mathbb T)$), but then put $f_n(t) = e^{i\xi_{n} t}$ for some sequence $\{\xi_n\}$ such that $\xi_n \to \infty$ and $\| f_n\|_{L^2} = C$ for all $n$. Then $\|f_n\| \not\to 0$ but by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, we have $\langle f_n ,g \rangle \to 0$ for all $g\in L^2(\mathbb T)$.

Comment: I mean Riemann-integrable. In our class we defined $||f_n||_{L_2}^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(t)|^2$

Comment: I guess if you require Riemann integrable functions to be bounded, then that solves the problem, but if you allow for improper Riemann integrals then Lorenzo Quarisa's concern is still a problem - a function $f$ can be Riemann integrable in the improper sense while $f^2$ is not; hene the $L^2$ doesn't make sense for such functions.

Comment: I've edited your question to improve some of the MathJax (the changes you should particularly note are the use of \| to write norms and \langle and \rangle for inner products). I'd also recommend writing genuine sentences instead of just line after line of formulae for the "what I've been thinking" part since not doing this made it much more difficult to understand what each line meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not true.

Consider the orthonormal basis $\{e_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ for $L^2[0, 2\pi]$, where $e_n(t) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{int}$.

Then for any $g \in L^2[0,2\pi]$ we have $\langle e_n, g\rangle \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, but $\|e_n\|_{L^2} = 1, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This counter example is so simple, I spent hours trying to find it !

Comment: Just as a small addition: $\textit{Every}$ orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,2\pi]$ yields a counterexample, since for every orthonormal basis $\|(\langle g, e_n \rangle)_{n\in \mathbb N}\|_2 = \|g\| < \infty$, hence $\langle g, e_n \rangle \to 0$ for all $g \in L^2[0,2\pi]$.